# Bootstrap menu dropdown not removing active class when changing tabs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a Bootstrap menu with a drop-down to move between tabs, this works fine but once the drop-down items are given an active class they do not seem to be removed when navigating to another tab from the drop-down menu. I'm sure I am just doing something simple wrong but I cannot figure out what it is?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
              Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="collapsed">
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Content for tab 1</div>   
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Content for tab 2</div> 
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">Content for tab 3</div> 
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">Content for tab 4</div> 
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">Content for tab 5</div> 
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vso9mzn/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated and working you need to add all the attributes that bootstrap need to works

add the class in the li of dropdown

```
<li class="dropdown">
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vso9mzn/5/
LINE 10.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this and is using Bootstrap 5, dropdowns inside of tabs are not supported due to issues with both usability and accessibility.  See docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#accessibility